# Merge string and variable as argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, middleman

I want to pass the string `'header__button'` and the response from method `classify(f)` as the argument `class` to `link_to`.

I tried

```
<%= link_to f, '/dashboard', class: 'header__button' classify(f) %>
```

but Ruby won't allow it. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass an array:

```
<%= link_to f, '/dashboard', class: ['header__button', classify(f)] %>
```

The documentation for [`tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) and [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) contains an example showing this usage (`link_to` calls `content_tag` to construct the `<a>` tag).

Comment: This is the most elegant solution for OP's special case. (i.e. concatenating CSS classes in a Rails tag helper)

Comment: It actually is a documented feature: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/tag / http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating the string and method:

```
<%= link_to f, '/dashboard', class: 'header__button ' + classify(f) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try interpolation using `"#{}"` as follows:

```
<%= link_to f, '/dashboard', class: "header__button #{classify(f)}" %>
```

Note that you need to be using double quotes `"#{}"`.

Comment: _Maybe I've missed something_, but it seems to be a valid answer. Downvoter, care to elaborate?

Comment: @Himmators please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can also concatenate with `<<`:

```
<%= link_to f, '/dashboard', class: 'header__button ' << classify(f) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will do the trick

```
<%= link_to f, '/dashboard', class: "header__button #{classify(f)}" %>
```

Comment: My version didn't work for the OP, not sure yours did :)